# How to uncheck all asp.net checkboxes with standard JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

I am trying to uncheck all asp.net checkboxes when I click a span of text, but for some reason it is not working. I have tried multiple solutions but nothing is working. Could you help me out? This is what I have so far.

I want to clear "CheckBoxList1" when clicking on  "clear". Btw, I am using only JavaScript, not JQuery. Thank you so much!

HTML

```
                    <div>
                        <label class="labels">Category:</label>
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="meat">Meat</asp:ListItem> 
                            <asp:ListItem Value="fish">Fish</asp:ListItem> 
                            <asp:ListItem Value="vegan">Vegan</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="clear">
                        <span id="clear" onclick="clear();">Clear Filters</span>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function clear() {
var chk1 = document.getElementById("CheckBoxList1");

for (var item in chk1.childNodes.length) {
    item.checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a better way than this, but it works, if you always know how many checkboxes there will be.

First, when the checkboxlist renders on a page, it renders as a `table`, so that makes it a bit awkward to get to the checkboxes (view the html in the browser tools.) Like this:

```
<table id="CheckBoxList1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" 
                    name="CheckBoxList1$CheckBoxList1_0" value="meat">
                <label for="CheckBoxList1_0">Meat</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" 
                    name="CheckBoxList1$CheckBoxList1_1" value="fish">
                <label for="CheckBoxList1_1">Fish</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" 
                    name="CheckBoxList1$CheckBoxList1_2" value="vegan">
                <label for="CheckBoxList1_2">Vegan</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the checkboxes render, they are given IDs that match the list's ID, plus `_n` appended.

For some reason I could not get the function called `clear` to fire. I had to change the name to `clear1`. I don't know why. Reserved word?

This is what I did. It's definitely a hack but works.

```
function clear1() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var chkbox = document.getElementById("CheckBoxList1_" + i);
        chkbox.checked = false;
    }
}
```

I didn't search, but I bet there's a better answer here on SO somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work first try because of you. Even though your code was a bit of a hack it gave me the basic understanding of checkboxes I needed to make it work. I took your code and tweaked it. Who would of though such a small issue would make such a big difference! Again, many thanks! Cheers!


Final result was like this:     

function clear1() {

var chk1 = document.getElementById(“CheckboList1);

for (var i = 0; i < chk1.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var chkbox = document.getElementById("CheckBoxList1_" + i);
        chkbox.checked = false;
    }
}

Comment: Clever! Thanks for replying. Please vote for all answers that help you.

Comment: I tried, but it says I don’t have enough reputation. I am kind of new here. But still voted anyway! Thank you for your help

Comment: Right. I can't remember what the rules are for starting to vote. Thanks.